# Откуда наши авторы берут свои вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

ВОПРОС ИЗМЕНЕН

Мы  крайне отрицательно относимся к  **домашним заданиям**, считаем, что это неправильно – выполнять чужую работу, просим дать собственный вариант ответа.

Но при этом мы охотно отвечаем на вопросы, происхождение которых не очень ясно. И вот оказалось, что три последних вопроса, заданных  **РАЗНЫМИ** авторами 07.08. 2020 года, имеют **ОБЩИЙ ИСТОЧНИК** – это форум https://studwork.org/

Просмотрев еще раз этот форум, я пришла к выводу, что это наш материал копируется там, так что к нашим участникам вопросов нет. Но зачем это делается и можно ли так делать – мне неясно.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates

Comment: Вот описание самой свежей лицензии https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru. У старых сообщений может быть более ранняя версия.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от цели каждого из нас.

Если цель - "поощрить" кого-то за хорошие вопросы (и поставить своеобразные "палки в колеса" авторам плохих), то тогда происхождение вопроса имеет принципиальное значение.
Если же цель - создать некий глобальный источник знаний, то происхождение вопроса не так уж и важно. Главное, чтобы вопрос был действительно хорош.

На мой взгляд, ограничения на домашние задания нужны в первую очередь для того, чтобы заставлять людей хотя бы минимально думать самостоятельно. Чтобы человек, столкнувшийся с непонятной ситуацией (не важно, в домашнем задании или при написании собственных мемуаров), не выкладывал свой вопрос сразу же сюда (мол, тут умные люди, они разберутся лучше), а попытался сначала найти правильный ответ сам.

Если же каждый раз, отвечая на вопрос, начинать искать по всему Интернету его источники, то может получиться так, что просто не будет хватать времени и сил на сам ответ.

Comment: У меня была очень благородная ЦЕЛЬ - найти контекст, которого всегда не хватает для хорошего ответа. Может быть, текст взят их художественного произведения? Набираю его  в поисковике - и выхожу на указанный форум. И вижу там все наши вопросы, заданные в один день, но разными участниками. Там же у них был один автор. Запрещая домашние задания, мы ставим благородную цель - научить думать самостоятельно.  В данной же ситуации мне непонятна мотивация действий этих участников - почему они так поступают? Мне кажется,что  нас попросту ИСПОЛЬЗУЮТ. Или я ошибаюсь, и здесь тоже всё этично и благородно?

Comment: @Sharon, да нет, вы правы: нас действительно используют. Но, к сожалению, мы практически ничего не можем с этим сделать. И в этом плане мы практически ничем не отличаемся от, например, авторов художественных произведений, чьи работы бесконтрольно копируются по всему Интернету. По сути, мы можем только принять это как данность. И смириться с этим. Какого-либо другого выхода лично я не вижу.

Comment: @Sharon "В Японии рассказывают истории о том, как великие буддийские поэты писали прекрасные хокку, вкладывали их в бутылку и отправляли плыть по реке или ближайшему ручью. Для любого писателя [и отвечающего на формуах — N.] это должно послужить примером исключительной непривязанности. Это тренировка альтруизма. Пишите и отпускайте свои тексты в мир... Несколько раз я чувствовала, что действительно написала что-то классное, но я просто отдавала листок со стихотворением заказчику и переходила к следующему" (Натали Голдберг "Чловек, который съел машину").

Comment: @Nektoid  Я давно уже делаю именно так: все, что я пишу,  доступно любому пользователю Сети. Ничего своего, никаких тайн  –  все для вас, люди.  Мне кажется, что это недостойно для человека – прийти в этот мир, воспользоваться трудами многих поколений и уйти, не оставив ему ничего. Впрочем, судить тоже никого не берусь, у каждого своя задача.  Научиться любить – мир, людей, Творца нашего, все живое –  тоже достойная цель. Так что давайте будем щедрыми и любящими.